# How can I programmatically scroll a WPF listview?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

Is it possible to programmatically scroll a WPF listview? I know winforms doesn't do it, right?

I am talking about say scrolling 50 units up or down, etc. Not scrolling an entire item height at once.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll have to grab the ScrollViewer from the ListView and use the methods exposed by it to override the scrolling.  You can also scroll by getting the main content area and using it's implementation of the [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx) interface.

Here's a little helper to get the ScrollViwer component of something like a ListBox, ListView, etc.

```cs
public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject o)
{
    // Return the DependencyObject if it is a ScrollViewer
    if (o is ScrollViewer)
    { return o; }
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o, i);
        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then you can just use .LineUp() and .LineDown() like this:

```cs
private void OnScrollUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(uiListView) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        // Logical Scrolling by Item
        // scrollViewer.LineUp();
        // Physical Scrolling by Offset
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset - 3);
    }
}

private void OnScrollDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(uiListView) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        // Logical Scrolling by Item
        // scrollViewer.LineDown();
        // Physical Scrolling by Offset
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset + 3);
    }
}
```

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            Content="Scroll Up"
            Click="OnScrollUp" />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            Content="Scroll Down"
            Click="OnScrollDown" />
    <ListView x:Name="uiListView">
        <!-- Content -->
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

The Logical scrolling exposed by LineUp and LineDown still scroll by item, if you want to scroll by a set amount you should use the ScrollToHorizontal/VerticalOffset that I've used above.  If you want more complex scrolling, take a look at the answer I've provided in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876994/in-wpf-how-do-i-adjust-the-scroll-increment-for-a-flowdocumentreader-with-viewin/973500#973500).

Comment: For both Vertical scroll down and Up, you are adding 3 to 'VerticalOffset'. Is it correct? For up, we need subtract 3, instead of add.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx)?
Alternatively, if it's not a specific item you brought into view, but an offset from the current position, you can use [BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598115.aspx).