# ListBox, VirtualizingStackPanel, and Smooth Scrolling in WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, listbox, scroll, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a `ListBox` that may have many rows of templated DB records, including an `Image`, bound to an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`.  Sometimes the collection could hold thousands of items.

The performance is great, but the scrolling is the default jumpy behavior.  I would like it to have smooth scrolling, so I unchecked `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll`.

Now I have smooth scrolling, but the performance is horrendous: the data is retrieved in a separate thread, and the thread finishes quickly, but it takes 10-20 seconds for the results to show in the `ListBox`.  I assume that this is because unchecking `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` changes the underlying `VirtualizingStackPanel` to a regular `StackPanel` and so it is loading the entire collection before displaying the results.

So my question is this: how do I retain the the smooth scrolling without sacrificing the `VirtualizingStackPanel` behavior and performance?

Comment: You can have both smooth scrolling and virtualization if you're prepared to use a little hack. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977929/wpf-listbox-with-a-listbox-ui-virtualization-and-scrolling/9875475#9875475) to a similar question for details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977929/wpf-listbox-with-a-listbox-ui-virtualization-and-scrolling/9875475
VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you uncheck CanContentScroll, you [lose virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx). And the answer is really frustrating: For now there is no out-of-the-box solution :(.

PS: This is not the first post here, asking [this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033841/is-it-possible-to-implement-smooth-scroll-in-a-wpf-listview).

Comment: I was afraid of that but had to ask.  I searched before asking but didn't find that post.  I might dig just a little bit more, but time is limited so I'll have to lose Smooth Scrolling for now.

Answer (score 5):

If you use .NET 4.5 (or 4.0 if you're willing to hack a bit) then there's an answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875475/117797).

[Note that @Guilluame's comment was here way before this answer but it wasn't particularly visible when skimming for answers.]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone searching at 2021 you can use solution like this:

You will keep scrolling and virtualization at the same time

```
            <ItemsControl x:Name="TestIC" Grid.Row="1"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Not a ListBox, so no selection option here. :(

Comment: I'm not great at WPF. But doesn't all the VirtualisingPanel.XXX in the ItemControl node duplicate the properties set on the virtualisingstackpanel?