# WPF ListBox with a ListBox - UI Virtualization and Scrolling

Tags: wpf, user-interface, listbox, scroll, virtualization

My prototype displays "documents" that contain "pages" that are 
represented by thumbnail images. Each document can have
any number of pages. For example, there might be 
1000 documents with 5 pages each, or 5 documents with 1000 pages
each, or somewhere inbetween. Documents do not contain other documents.
In my xaml markup I have a `ListBox`, whose `ItemsTemplate` 
references an innerItemsTemplate that also has a `ListBox`. I want the
2 levels of selected items so that I can perform various operations
on documents or pages (delete, merge, move to new location, etc).
The innerItemsTemplate `ListBox` uses a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

For the scenario where I have a large number of documents with a few
pages each (say, 10000 documents with 5 pages each), the scrolling
works great thanks to the UI Virtualization by the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.
However, I have problems if I have a large number of pages. A document
with 1000 pages will only display about 50 at a time (whatever fits on the screen), and when I scroll down, the outer `ListBox` moves to the next document, skipping the 950
pages or so that were not visible. Along with that, there is no
`VirtualzingWrapPanel` so the app memory really increases.

I'm wondering if I am going about this the right way, especially
since it is sort of difficult to explain! I would like to be able to display
10000 documents with 1000 pages each (only showing whatever fits on the screen),
using UI Virtualization, and also smooth scrolling.

How can I make sure the scrolling moves through all of the pages in document 
before it displays the next document, and still keep UI virtualization?
The scrollbar seems to only move to the next document.

Does it seem logical to represent "documents" and "pages" -
with my current method of using a `ListBox` within a `ListBox`?

I would very much appreciate any ideas you have.
Thank You.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer here is surprising:

- If you use `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` you will get the behavior you are experiencing, where the control scrolls "by item" so you jump over a whole document at once, BUT
- If you use `TreeView` instead, the control will scroll smoothly so you can scroll through your document and into the next one, but it will still be able to virtualize.

I think the reason the WPF team chose this behavior is that `TreeView`commonly has items that are larger than the visible area, whereas typically `ListBox`es don't.

In any case, it is trivial in WPF to make a `TreeView` look and act like a `ListBox` or `ItemsControl` by simply modifying the `ItemContainerStyle`.  This is very straightforward.  You can roll your own or just copy over the appropriate template from the system theme file.

So you will have something like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding documents}">
  <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <ContentPresenter /> <!-- put your desired container style here  with a ContentPresenter inside -->
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:Document}">
      <Border BorderThickness="2"> <!-- your document frame will be more complicated than this -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding pages}">
          ...
        </ItemsControl>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Getting pixel-based scrolling and ListBox-style multiselect to work together**

If you use this technique to get pixel-based scrolling, your outer ItemsControl which shows the documents cannot be a ListBox (because ListBox is not a subclass of TreeView or TreeViewItem).  Thus you lose all of ListBox's multiselect support.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to use these two features together without including some of your own code for one feature or the other.

If you need both sets of functionality in the same control, you have basically several options:

1. Implement multi-selection yourself in a subclass of TreeViewItem.  Use TreeViewItem instead of TreeView for the outer control, since it allows multiple children to be selected.  In the template inside ItemsContainerStyle: Add a CheckBox around the ContentPresenter, template bind the CheckBox to IsSelected, and style the CheckBox with control template to get the look you want.  Then add your own mouse event handlers to handle Ctrl-Click and Shift-Click for multiselect.
2. Implement pixel-scrolled virtualization yourself in a subclass of VirtualizingPanel.  This is relatively simple, since most of VirtualizingStackPanel's complexity is related to non-pixel scrolling and container recycling.  [Dan Crevier's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/tags/VirtualizingTilePanel/default.aspx) has some useful infromation for understanding VirtualizingPanel.

Comment: This approach indeed works for me as far as UI Virtualization. Now I just need to get the ListBox like behavior for selecting items (pages or documents in this case). How can I get multiple and extended selection modes similar to ListBox?

Comment: Also, I'm setting the  ItemsPanelTemplate within the ItemsControl to a WrapPanel, which does not seem to wrap when I resize the app - it seems to behave more like a stackPanel. Overall, I feel the answer above by Ray does get me going in the right direction.

Comment: I am so glad I stumbled across this post it saved me pulling all of my hair out.

Comment: Wow! You are opened my eyes! Thanks a lot for that answer!

Answer (score 56):

It is possible to achieve smooth scrolling VirtualizingStackPanels in WPF 4.0 without sacrificing virtualization if you're prepared to use reflection to access private functionality of the VirtualizingStackPanel. All you have to do is set the private IsPixelBased property of the VirtualizingStackPanel to true.

Note that in .Net 4.5 there's no need for this hack as you can set VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel".

To make it really easy, here's some code:

```
public static class PixelBasedScrollingBehavior 
{
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(PixelBasedScrollingBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, HandleIsEnabledChanged));

    private static void HandleIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vsp = d as VirtualizingStackPanel;
        if (vsp == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var property = typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel).GetProperty("IsPixelBased",
                                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Pixel-based scrolling behaviour hack no longer works!");
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            property.SetValue(vsp, true, new object[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            property.SetValue(vsp, false, new object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this on a ListBox, for example, you would do:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel PixelBasedScrollingBehavior.IsEnabled="True">
          </VirtualizingStackPanel>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This was really helpful, +1. For future visitors using .NET 4.5, you need to set `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"` on your `ListBox` itself, not on the `VirtualizingStackPanel` that holds the content.

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix: have you installed .Net 4.5 on your machine? Because that is an in-place update to .Net 4.0, I think it breaks this hack.

Comment: Yes... I have .NET4.5 installed, but the program was targeting .NET4.0. I made my own custom control to fix this. but thx anyway.

Comment: This has strange side-effects. First, after loading a few thousand items and scrolling to the end, all items are invisible until the list is changed again or I scroll a bit up. Second, the scrolling moves the view partly by entire item heights and partly by a fraction of it, so it's very inconsistent. All in all, this doesn't work for me. (Win7, VS2010, .NET 4.0)

Comment: Somehow I accidentally gave this a downvote, and now I can't reverse it. Good answer, and thanks for this info.

Answer (score 21):

.NET 4.5 now has the `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="ScrollUnit"` property. I just converted one of my TreeViews to a ListBox and the performance was noticeably better.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.scrollunit(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me.  Seems a couple of simple attributes will do it (.NET 4.5)

```
<ListBox            
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"/>
```

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel` doesn't have those properties. Did you mean `VirtualizingPanel`?

Comment: 3 years since my response and I'm afraid I'm not sure. VS doesn't complain about `VirtualizingStackPanel` - but when I hover over it, the tip displays `VirtualizingPanel` instead. My guess is that the former is a back-supported alias for the latter.

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel` derives from `VirtualizingPanel`. `IsVirtualizingProperty` and `ScrollUnitProperty` are defined on the base class. You can reference them via the subtype but it's perhaps clearer to do so from the type that declares the properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to preface this answer with a question: Does the user have to see each and every thumbnail within every item in the list at all times?

If the answer to that question is 'no', then perhaps it would be feasible to limit the number of visible pages within the inner item template (given that you have indicated the scrolling works well with, say, 5 pages) and use a separate 'selected item' template that is larger and displays all pages for that document? Billy Hollis explains how to 'pop' a selected item out in a listbox on dnrtv [episode 115](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115)

Comment: no the user does not have to see each and every thumbnail within every item in the list at all times - they just need to be able to scroll to get to other items