# WPF Remove Extra Space on bottom of ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am getting a large amount of space under my custom listbox if I add an item with multiple lines of text.  What can I do to solve this?

[image]

My code

```
<!-- List Item Hover -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverFocusStyle" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF013B73" Offset="0.501"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF014A8F" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF003363" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- List Item Selected -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LostFocusStyle" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
            <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF091F34" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF002F5C" Offset="0.4"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- List Item Highlight -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListItemHighlight" Color="#FFE38E27" />

<!-- List Item UnHighlight -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListItemUnHighlight" Color="#FF6FB8FD" />

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="ListItem_GotFocus"></EventSetter>
    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="ListItem_LostFocus"></EventSetter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomListData" DataType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Margin="-2,0,0,-1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource ListItemUnHighlight}"
                    FontSize="24"
                    Tag="{Binding .}"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    MinHeight="55"
                    Cursor="Hand"
                    FontFamily="Arial"
                    FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
                    Background="{StaticResource LostFocusStyle}"
                    MouseMove="ListItem_MouseOver"
                    >
                <Label.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="editMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Label.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Margin="15,0,40,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
            </Label>
            <Image 
                Tag="{Binding .}"
                Source="{Binding}"
                Margin="260,0,0,0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Stretch="None"
                Width="16"
                Height="22" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:ImageLoader}"  MethodName="LoadImages"  />
</Window.DataContext>


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="320" Background="#FF021422" BorderBrush="#FF1C4B79" >

<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomListData }" />
    </Style>

</ListBox.Resources>
```

CodeBehind

```
public static class ImageLoader
{
    public static List<String> LoadImages()
    {
        List<String> images = new List<String>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            if (x == 5)
            {
                images.Add("Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test TestTest Test Test  Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test" + x);
            }
            else
            {
                images.Add("Test " + x);
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently you are scrolling item by item.

The problem is because Test 5 in your listbox is the next item that would be displayed (and it's larger than the empty space shown in the picture you included). Only once that space is big enough for Test 5 to be fully displayed will it actually get shown.

However, if you want smooth scrolling instead of item by item scrolling, simply set the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll property to false.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="320" Background="#FF021422" BorderBrush="#FF1C4B79" >
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That fixed my scroll bar size change and the blank space at the bottom.  Thanks so much for the explanation.

Comment: This will disable UI virtualization though.

Comment: @Stephen Drew - True it will disable virtualization, with the item sizes being different height and trying to get proper representation in the scrollbar it sort of makes sense why they designed it that way... but this is an answer from almost 4 years ago, and I believe there are some more options with .NET 4.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977929/wpf-listbox-with-a-listbox-ui-virtualization-and-scrolling

Comment: Indeed, these options are very welcome. Now to get approval for moving to .NET 4.5 - hopefully the demise of XP will accelerate it.

Answer (score 5):

As a quick answer if someone comes around this in .Net 4.5

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
```

will do the trick. For better explanation look at:
http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/07/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-11-new-features-for-the-virtualizingpanel/

Comment: Thanks for a help!

Comment: Indeed this comment is very important because this way you don't lose virtualization.  That ScrollUnit option helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: No worries mate :)