# Listbox style with items that contains lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am building a webscaper to scrape torrents, backend is already done and now I am kind of stuck on the UI(using WPF).
I want to display the torrents on a `ListBox` but corresponding to the query (I call it term as in search term).

The data passed to the `ListBox` is:

```
List<SearchTermData>
```

This is the structure:

```
public class SearchTermData {
   public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
   public List<Torrent> Torrents { get; set; } = new List<Torrent>();
}
```

Torrent is this:

```
public class Torrent {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

I generally want the `ListBox` to display a `Grid`. Column 1 will be the "SearchTerm" and column 2 will be a `StackPanel` of "Torrents" (`List<Torrent>`).

It displays the "SearchTermData" correctly, with the `SearchTerm` name and the general structure, but it fails to display the `StackPanel` of the `Torrents`.

This is my XAML style:

```
<Style x:Key="TorrentListbox" TargetType="ListBox">
   <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Black}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
   <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource TermItem}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TermItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DSGray}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Black}" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Visibility="Visible">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=SearchTerm}" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Black}" Style="{StaticResource KeyLabel}" Foreground="{StaticResource DSGreen}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Torrents}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                              <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DSGreen}">
                                 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Torrent}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                       <DataTemplate>
                                          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Visibility="Visible">
                                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                             <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                             <Label Content="Size:" Style="{StaticResource KeyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                             <Label Content="{Binding Path=Size}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                          </Grid>
                                       </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                 </ItemsControl>
                              </Border>
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl>
                  </StackPanel>
               </Grid>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

If anyone can help me figure out the issue I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your items template for `Torrent`, there is a nested `ItemsControl` that is not needed and that is binding to a property `Torrent` on an item of type `Torrent`, which does not exist.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Torrent}">
```

The control template below should work. I removed the redundant `ItemsControl` and the `StackPanel` as well, because it only contains a single control, which is why you do not need it.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
      <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Visibility="Visible">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Label Content="{Binding Path=SearchTerm}" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Black}" Style="{StaticResource KeyLabel}" Foreground="{StaticResource DSGreen}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
         <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Torrents}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DSGreen}">
                     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Visibility="Visible">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Content="Size:" Style="{StaticResource KeyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Size}" Style="{StaticResource PropertyLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                     </Grid>
                  </Border>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

### An Alternative Using ListView with GridView

Since you want to display two columns, you could alternatively use a `ListView` in combination with a [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-display-listview-contents-by-using-a-gridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). This way, you would actually have *real* columns.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchTerms}">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DSGray}"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Black}" />
         <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
         <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
         <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" /> 
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                  <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                     <GridViewRowPresenter/>
                  </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Search Term">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=SearchTerm}" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Torrents">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Torrents}">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green">
                              <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" Visibility="Visible">
                                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                 <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                 <Label Content="Size:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                 <Label Content="{Binding Path=Size}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                              </Grid>
                           </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Ok, so firstly I tried to use the first option first instead of my own, it does display the torrents but the List<Torrents> is basically bound by the size of the of Term. to put into words, I tried to generate a test List that contains 5 Terms, each with 20 Torrents. The in the current window size, the Term displays only 17 Torrents, and if I scroll down, instead of showing the rest of them, it moves to the next term. Any idea why?

Comment: Also I want to tried your suggested ListView Template, but I need it as a style as it used in multiple windows and files... I tried to modify it to a style myself but being unfamiliar with Listview, I didn't have much success.

Comment: @DavidShnayder The scrolling issue is cause by the default _logical scrolling_. That means scrolling by items, not pixels. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033841/is-it-possible-to-implement-smooth-scroll-in-a-wpf-listview) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977929/wpf-listbox-with-a-listbox-ui-virtualization-and-scrolling?noredirect=1&lq=1) on how ro deactivate it.

Comment: @DavidShnayder  As for extracting the styles in the second approach, you can just move out the item container style and the cell data templates and share them in a resource dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for all your help mate! I really learned a lot.