# Partially vertically scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` that contains two columns - column one contains a Toggle Button, column two contains an `Expander` with multiple controls within it. If the `expander` is collapsed, the overall scrolling of the `ListBox` works fine. However, if the `Expander` is open and the expander contains a large quantity of items, the `ListBox` will scroll the entire row size, often not showing part of the `expander` list.

This would be similar to placing an image in the list box that is larger than the viewable area of the list box. In this case, if you click the scrollbar, you would want to "step" down the image, without it scrolling off the screen in one click.

Is there a setting for the `ListBox` that will allow the partial scrolling as I've described?  My `listBox` is defined in a `xaml`, the controls are added via C# code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried turning on smooth scrolling by setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to false?  This is what controls whether the `ScrollViewer` will scroll an item at a time, or smoothly with partial items available.

> "ScrollViewer currently allows two scrolling modes: smooth
>   pixel-by-pixel scrolling (CanContentScroll = false) or discrete
>   item-by-item scrolling (CanContentScroll = true). Currently WPF
>   supports UI virtualization only when scrolling by item. Pixel-based
>   scrolling is also called 'physical scrolling' and item-based scrolling
>   is also called 'logical scrolling'."
>   (From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724593/why-setting-scrollviewer-cancontentscroll-to-false-disable-virtualization)).

If you have a lot of items in your `ListBox`, this may not be an ideal solution, however, because it turns off Virtualization, and therefore may have a performance impact.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924089/listbox-virtualizingstackpanel-and-smooth-scrolling-in-wpf) to see more about smooth scrolling and virtualization. (One answer suggests a hack that allows for smooth scrolling and virtualization).

Comment: Brian S, that is the solution I was looking for.  That allows the partial scrolling.  Thank you.