# WPF - Smooth scrolling in ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, smooth-scrolling

how is it possible to create a smooth scrolling ScrollViewer in WPF?

Actually, when Scrolling with my Mouse a little downwards, it jumps for some pixels. But i want it to smoothly scroll down.
My code looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="spTasks" Grid.Column="1" >
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SmartTaskOverview2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,20" />
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: What is the content inside the `ScrollViewer`.  Is that full of string or something else?

Comment: I added some code, but Grid can be excluded, so only a Stackpanel is inside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement smooth scroll in a WPF listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033841/is-it-possible-to-implement-smooth-scroll-in-a-wpf-listview)

Comment: not a duplicate, i don't have got a ListView. Also manipulating the code does't work for me