# Vertical Scrollbar does automatically "jumping" forward

Tags: c#, wpf

If i open a `TreeView Item` which `Header` is longer than the control, the scrollbar automatically jumps to the end of this item, which can be very disturbing... [image]

Any workaround so that the scrollbar dont jump "automatically"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033918/73804

Comment: tried ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False", not working

Comment: Try VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"

Comment: @Patrick i just tried, no success, but thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to handle the `RequestBringIntoView` of the `TreeViewItem` containers:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="OnRequestBringIntoView"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

---

```
private void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e) => e.Handled = true;
```

But please remember to always provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: Wuhu, @mm8 always my men! Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can handling the **ScrollChanged** event from **ScrollViewer** inside your **TreeView**.

So, you can write these lines of code here:

```
var element1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sender as TreeView, 0) as X; 
// Where X is the object inside your TreeView. Eg. StackPanel, Border...

var scrollviewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element1, 0) as ScrollViewer;
//Goes to the beggining of your content
scrollviewer.ScrollToLeftEnd();

// Another way is...
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset + e.ExtentHeightChange);
```