# Listboxes, scrolling in sync

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, listbox

I have 2 listboxes, same size, next to each other. Basically I am using them to represent linked items...Similar to having 2 columns and a number of rows in excel, with say, first name in one and last name in the other.

I am wondering if I could make it so that when one listbox is scrolled, the other listbox scrolls in sync with it?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Maybe you should consider the DataGrid (part of the downloadable WPF Toolkit)

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ScrollSynchronization.aspx

Comment: See (dup?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009036/how-can-i-programmatically-scroll-a-wpf-listview

Comment: Thank you very much. Does exactly what I was after.