# How to increase ScrollViewer Speed programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I need to increase my `ScrollViwer` speed through program.

```
   <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollTile"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseWheel="scrollTile_PreviewMouseWheel">
       <StackPanel  Canvas.Left="45" Canvas.Top="0" x:Name="MetroStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#00000000" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I didn't find any method to increase scrolling speed through c#. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check this ->  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876994/adjust-flowdocumentreaders-scroll-increment-when-viewingmode-set-to-scroll`

Answer (score 0):

Just put ScrollViewer

```
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <StackPanel ... />
   </ScrollViewer>
```