# WPF how to increase ScrollBar arrow button click scroll speed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, scrollbar

I have an `UserControl` containing a `ScrollViewer` with "sychronized" `ScrollBar` associated with it binding both the `ViewportSize` and `Maximum` `ScrollBar`'s properties, simplified code:

```
//xaml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scViewer" <!--and its content-->/>
<ScrollBar ViewportSize="{Binding ViewportWidth, ElementName=scViewer}" 
           Maximum="{Binding ScrollableWidth, ElementName=scViewer}" x:Name="scHBar"
           Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="HScrollBar_Scroll"/>
//code behind
private void HScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    scViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.NewValue);//and the other way around
}
```

It works as expected, except when user clicks up/down arrows on `ScrollBar` the speed is *very* slow, 0.1px for each click to be precise, which requires user to click 10 times(!) to scroll a pixel. Strangely enough, the mouse wheel scrolling speed is fine just as dragging the bar speed is.
The only solution which comes to my mind is multiplying the `e.NewValue` delta, however I dont know whether the source was one of the arrow buttons(not mouse wheel or bar drag) so it would break every other type of interaction.
There are quite a lot questions about scrolling speed of mouse wheel, however I was unable to find a single one mentioning the speed when clicking `ScrollBar`'s arrow buttons. How do I change the ScrollBar's *arrow buttons* click scroll speed?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/973500/442444

Comment: thanks but please note it is not what I am not asking about - I already have the Mouse *wheel* working, the trouble are the *arrow buttons* on top/bottom of the ScrollBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Scrollbar` also has properties `SmallChange` and `LargeChange`, defaulting to 0.1 and 1 respectively. The first one is controlling the speed of scrolling when clicking the arrow buttons, so changing the value:

```
<ScrollBar SmallChange="30" LargeChange="150"
       ViewportSize="{Binding ViewportWidth, ElementName=scViewer}" 
       Maximum="{Binding ScrollableWidth, ElementName=scViewer}" x:Name="scHBar"
       Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="HScrollBar_Scroll"/>
```

worked for me.