# How to change the scroll bar speed of the FlowDocumentReader?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, scrollview, scrollbar

I have been searching the answer for this question for two days, but still can not find a good answer. The most relevant answer is from this link: [Adjust FlowDocumentReader's Scroll Increment When ViewingMode Set to Scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876994/adjust-flowdocumentreaders-scroll-increment-when-viewingmode-set-to-scroll) .

However, the code in that link cannot be compiled in my VS 2015. The "Scrollhelper" and "Demo" caused the error, and I do not know how to fix it. :(

So, is there a way to set the scrolling speed in FlowDocumentReader? Any example would be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add snippet of your code?

Comment: @Prajwal Sorry, I literally do not know how to do it, so I don't have a snippet. With regard to the link I mentioned, I just copied the code in the link, you can check it out by clicking the link in my post, if you are interested. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The code in that answer can well be compiled. It is just not complete. You'll have to add a few things like e.g. the `ScrollHelper` class declaration around the attached property declaration.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your comment, Clemens. I am not sure what ScrollHelper class is used for and how to decalre it, can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks again.